# Inserting more than 32000 characters data in Text column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a column data type text. i want to insert data in this column using SSMS(can use other tools also) with insert statement.

```
Update dbo.xyz set data = 'query of length 31232 characters' where id = 1
```

How can i insert it When i do it through SSMS only first 8000 Characters are inserted.

Comment: `text` has been deprecated since 2005. Is it not about time you considered heeding the advice given in the SQL Server documentation, every version since then, to move to using `varchar(max)` instead?

Comment: yeah, You were right. but i can't do that as the database i am working on is shared. i can't change the column data types at all. thats why i needed help to do so.

Comment: So, you can't go and talk to the people with whom this database is shared and say something along the lines of "isn't it ridiculous that we've ignored Microsoft's advice for more than a decade? Shouldn't we apply a little bit of due care and attention and clean up some of our messes rather than creating more technical debt?". If not, I'd suggest the next best solution is to find a job where people *do* care about the quality of their work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your `'query of length 31232 characters'`, I give you an example.

I create the table xyz similar to yours with id and a column Col of datatype `text`.

I then inserted 2 rows and made 2 updates to it, note that in one case I update with `replicate('a', 32000)` and in other with `replicate(cast('a' as varchar(max)), 32000)`, in the first case only 8000 characters were inserted, but it's not `INSERT` problem.

The problem here is that if you don't explicitely cast to `varchar(max)` your string is truncated to `8000` characters.

```
create table dbo.xyz(id int, col text);

insert into dbo.xyz(id) values(1), (2);

Update dbo.xyz 
set col = replicate('a', 32000) 
where id = 1;

Update dbo.xyz 
set col = replicate(cast('a' as varchar(max)), 32000) 
where id = 2;

select id, len(cast(col as varchar(max)))
from dbo.xyz;
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Kshitij! What @sepupic says is completely correct. In your example you need to cast the data you try to insert i either varchar(max) or nvarchar(max). If you don't it will be treated as a varchar with a max length of 8000.

Answer (score 0):

You can create VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) data types which enables data storage up to 2 GB